# Installing libudev for arm on x64 Ubuntu

Tags: apt, arm, cross-compilation

I'm trying to cross-compile a software using `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` on my x64 Ubuntu. I have tried to do the following steps to install `libudev:armhf`:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
```

Added these two lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe
deb [arch=armel,armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty main universe`
```

Then I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It gives me such error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

If I try `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev:armhf` I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:


   libudev-dev:armhf : Depends: libudev1:armhf (= 204-5ubuntu20) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`sudo apt-cache policy libudev1:{amd64,armhf}` gives

```
libudev1:
  Installed: 204-5ubuntu20.20
  Candidate: 204-5ubuntu20.20
  Version table:
 *** 204-5ubuntu20.20 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     204-5ubuntu20 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libudev1:armhf:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 204-5ubuntu20
  Version table:
     204-5ubuntu20 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty/main armhf Packages
```

How will I add armhf to my system to cross-compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, to fix the warnings you're getting on the downloads, you need to qualify *all* the non-ports entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` with `[arch=amd64,i386]`.

Second, you can't install `libudev1` with your current setup because multiarch packages need to be installed with the same version on all architectures. You already have 204-5ubuntu20.20 installed on `amd64`, but that version isn't available in the repositories you've configured. To be able to install the package for `armhf`, you need to add `trusty-updates` for `armhf` too:

```
deb [arch=armel,armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-updates main universe
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need ubuntu-ports? trusty seems to have armhf in the official archive, see: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/204-5ubuntu20.20

I would suggest to remove the lines you have added to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and try again

Comment: If I remove the ports and try to install libudev:armhf it just says Unable to locate package

Comment: The main archives still only carry `amd64` and `i386`, even in [Zesty](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/).